# Matching function in R: `match.fun()` vs `deparse(substitute())` vs supplying function "directly"

Tags: r, function

`fun1()`, `fun2()` and `fun3()` seem all to work as expected:

```r
fun1 <- function(fun, x) {
  fun(x)
}

fun1(mean, 1:10)
fun1(as.character, 1:10)
fun1(notafun, 1:10)

fun2 <- function(fun, x) {
  fun <- match.fun(fun)
  fun(x)
}

fun2(mean, 1:10)
fun2(as.character, 1:10)
fun2(notafun, 1:10)

fun3 <- function(fun, x) {
  fun <- deparse(substitute(fun))
  do.call(fun, list(x))
}

fun3(mean, 1:10)
fun3(as.character, 1:10)
fun3(notafun, 1:10)
```

Is one strategy to be preferred in general? So far, I only notice that `match.fun()` also works if `fun` is specified as a string (e.g. `"mean"`).

My use case is a non-exported function in a package for local use (where it is not a limitation if I can't specify `fun()` as a string). Is there any benefits of using `match.fun()` instead of supplying functions "directly" (like in `fun1()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, documentation! Here are relevant sections from `?match.fun`:

> When called inside functions that take a function as argument, extract the desired function object while avoiding undesired matching to objects of other types.

> If `FUN` is a function, it is returned. If it is a symbol (for example, enclosed in backquotes) or a character vector of length one, it will be looked up using `get` in the environment of the parent of the caller.

Thus, `match.fun` has two main benefits:

1. It gives users the option of passing strings and symbols instead of functions.
2. It provides *type safety*, as the return value is always a function. This makes your source code not only more robust, but also more transparent: it is not necessary to read the documentation of your `fun2` to know that its argument `fun` must specify a function.

And it provides these benefits at virtually no cost to performance:

```r
x1 <- mean
x2 <- "mean"
x3 <- quote(mean)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(match.fun(x1), match.fun(x2), match.fun(x3), times = 1000L)
# Unit: nanoseconds
#           expr  min   lq     mean median   uq  max neval
#  match.fun(x1)  287  328  362.481    328  328 1681  1000
#  match.fun(x2) 1599 1681 1820.892   1681 1763 7544  1000
#  match.fun(x3) 1599 1640 1783.049   1681 1722 7339  1000
```

For these reasons, it is almost always better to validate with `match.fun` before trying to evaluate a function call (as in your `fun2`) than to wait and hope that a call can be evaluated (as in your `fun1` and `fun3`). This principle holds even if your function is not exported and even if you never pass strings or symbols, because transparency (see 2) makes your source code easier to read and maintain.

Your `fun3` is unique in that it allows users to pass unevaluated expressions, but that approach is problematic for multiple reasons:

1. It will not work as expected inside of other functions; see @Hong Ooi's comment/answer.
2. You cannot pass functions accessed with a double or triple colon operator, or anonymous functions, or, more generally, any expression evaluating indirectly to a function:

   ```r
   fun3(base::mean, 1:10)
   # Error in `base::mean`(1:10) : could not find function "base::mean"
   fun3(function(x) mean(x), 1:10)
   # Error in `function(x) mean(x)`(1:10) : 
   #   could not find function "function(x) mean(x)"
   fun3(match.fun(mean), 1:10)
   # Error in `match.fun(mean)`(1:10) : 
   #   could not find function "match.fun(mean)"
   ```
3. Even if it *does* work as you expect, it is mostly smoke and mirrors: if the result of `deparse(substitute(fun))` is a string naming a function accessible from the calling environment, then there was no need for `deparse(substitute(fun))` in the first place, because `fun` would have evaluated to that function anyway. It does extra work for nothing:

   ```r
   microbenchmark::microbenchmark(fun1(mean, 1:10), fun3(mean, 1:10), times = 1000L)
   # Unit: microseconds
   #              expr   min     lq      mean median     uq    max neval
   #  fun1(mean, 1:10) 2.009  2.378  2.700055  2.460  2.788 14.350  1000
   #  fun3(mean, 1:10) 9.020 10.127 10.991813 10.701 11.480 52.398  1000
   ```

In summary, it is good practice to use `match.fun` whenever you expect functions as arguments. You might avoid `match.fun` if you want to accept functions but *not* strings or symbols, but in that situation it would still be good practice to have a test:

```r
function(FUN, ...) {
  if (!is.function(FUN)) {
    stop("oops")
  }
  ## do stuff
}
```

Comment: `fun3` will _fail_ if called inside an enclosing function, eg `g <- function(f, x) fun3(f, x); g(mean, 1:10)`

Comment: In general, try to avoid nonstandard evaluation tricks unless absolutely necessary

Comment: Thanks - I've referred to your answer and mentioned yet another issue: `fun3(base::mean, x)` fails.

Answer (score 1):

One key difference is that `fun3` will *fail* if called inside an enclosing function, eg:

```
g <- function(f, x)
{
    fun3(f, x)
}

g(mean, 1:10)
# Error in f(1:10) : could not find function "f"
```

In general, try to avoid nonstandard evaluation tricks unless absolutely necessary.